# jquery Form - Data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

im currently trying to learn forms and save the value in a database. And i found "jquery form" from malsup very easy to use.

But i now i have a problem.

I want to send additional data with the informations from the form.

So how i understand it, it should work like that. using 'data'. But the information within data(key1, key2). I cant "read" them in my php file.

Here are the jquery form options and the php file.

```
var options = {

        data: {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
},
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            console.log("beforeSend");
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete)
        {
            console.log("uploadProgress")
        },
        success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form, response)
        {
            console.log("success")
        },
        complete: function(data, response)
        {
            //response text from the server.
            console.log("complete") 
        }

    };


<?PHP

    $adress = $_POST['searching_adress'];
    $productname = $_POST['searching_productname'];
    $city = $_POST['searching_city'];
    $description = $_POST['searching_description'];
    $searchingfloor = $_POST['searching_floor'];    
    $mail = $_POST['searching_email'];

    $key1 = $_POST['key1'];

    var_dump($_POST);

    $response = array('adress' => $adress, 'productname' => $productname,'city'=>$city,'description'=>$description,'searchingfloor'=>$searchingfloor,'mail'=>$mail,'pathid'=>$xhr,'type'=>$key1);
    echo json_encode($response);


?>
```

Comment: Where do you actually submit the post from client-side code?  It looks like your server-side code is trying to read values that were never supplied to it.

Comment: @David I Hope i understand what you want, the submit is this "<form id="contact" action="files-raw.php" method="POST">" . But the input from the field are sended. I can see everything with var_dump($_POST);, just the additional data not.

Comment: Then how is your JavaScript code managing the form post?  If you're just submitting a standard form and not using AJAX then your JavaScript options aren't used because they're not relevant to that.  All you have in the posted code is a JavaScript object.  There's no posted code which shows how you *use* that object.

Comment: @David i put everything here on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ceErF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Jquery Form plugin When form is submitted the form fields according to thier names will be posted to respective server file.

So here if you want to add extra parameters then you can simply add some hidden fields in your form and try to execute  your code.

When form is posted you will get the extra fileds too.

Comment: I add a hidden field (<li style="display: none;"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="" name="myParamName"></li>) but now i get just ["myParamName"]=>  string(0) "" with var_dump($_POST); in php.

Comment: Yes of course because you haven't provide any value to myParamName.
<li style="display: none;"><input type="text" value="yourValue" placeholder="" name="myParamName"></li>) If you do like this then you will get ['myParamName'] => yourValue in $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

If you extra parameter to passed with jquery form. Use hidden field inside the form. So when form is submitted, it send extra parameter to php file

Comment: I add a hidden field (<li style="display: none;"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="" name="myParamName"></li>) but now i get just ["myParamName"]=> string(0) "" with var_dump($_POST); in php.

Comment: Use this <input type="hidden" value="" placeholder="" name="myParamName">

Comment: I try this as well, but the problem now is, the additional data is posted, i can see it with var_dump but its not added to the hidden field.                                                                
  ["myParamName"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["submit"]=>
  string(18) "registry"
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "myParamName"
  ["value"]=>
  string(7) "value33"
                                                                      i write down my javascript here on codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ceErF

Answer (score 0):

Check if the keyvalues are really posted from the other page. If not you can create a hidden input to post the values. This also works for aditional information.
Here is the code:
`<input type="hidden" value="test" name="test" />`